# ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I access ParentActionViewContext in Asp.Net Core, I used following commands, but in core they are not available.
`ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();`, `ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.ViewBag.Model as MyViewModel`

I was not able to find anything regarding these due to scarcity of information on .Net Core.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

- To get route data, you need to use `ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor` instead of `ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext` now:

  ```
  ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteValues.Values;
  ```
- Regarding getting `Model`. Controller class has own properties:

  ```
  public dynamic ViewBag { get; }
  public ViewDataDictionary ViewData { get; set; }
  ```

  so you may use

  ```
  var myModel = this.ViewData.Model as MyViewModel;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find `ParentActionViewContext` because there are no Child Actions in ASP.Net Core. They have been replaced by [View Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components).

You can just invoke them and pass any data you want, without going through the request pipeline again (i.e. no model binding, filters or independent http context)

- There is a nice introductory article for the topic [here](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2016/01/02/goodbye-child-actions-hello-view-components.aspx)